# arm assembly cannot access GPIO

Tags: assembly, arm

I want to light up a LED on the STM32F4-discovery board. The processor is STM32F429ZIT6. My assembly code is the following:

```
    TTL LLED
    AREA Myprog, CODE, READONLY

    ENTRY
    EXPORT __main

__main
        LDR r5,=0x40021800; MODERG
        LDR r7,=0x4002180C; GPIOG_PUPDR
        MOV r8,#0x04000000
        STR r8, [r5]
        STR r8, [r7]
        LDR r8,=0x00000000; to set PG13
        STR r8,[r6]
        MOV r5,#0x20000000
        MOV r8,#0xFFFFFFFF
        STR r8, [r5]
        END
```

I checked with the ST-Link debugger the memory in address 0x40021800, but there are no changes after the STR command, although the values of the registers are correct. The documentation of ST is so so bad, totally zero examples. In internet 0 info about the assembly and ARM. In the books there is one example about the UART, but nothing about GPOI. I spent the whole Sun and I'm getting crazy right now. HEEEEEEELP!!!!

Comment: If you find ST Micros documentation bad, you will probably find the documentation of competing chips abysmal. (hint: It's not *that* bad)

Comment: It depends for what purpose u r using  it. In my case I want to program a simple GPIO in ASM and it's a real drama.

Comment: Have you tried goole with STM32F4+GPIO?

Comment: Not exactly STM32F4+GPIO, but Assembly STM32F4 GPIO with 100 other combinations, since I wanted to filter the C code examples.

Comment: I am glad your problem is solved.  I looks like you use `[r6]` un-initialized in the code you posted.  Maybe it was suppose to be `[r7]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In STM32 (as in most Cortex-M3 microcontrollers) you first need to enable the clock for a peripheral to modify any of its registers. So before you set anything in GPIOG registers you need to enable clock for that in appropriate RCC register, probably RCC->AHBENR, the bit would be RCC_AHBENR_GPIOGEN. This applies to almost any peripheral, like GPIO, I2C, SPI, timers, ... Default value for these "clock enable" bits is 0 in 99% of cases (with small exceptions).

Comment: Hi Freddie. Good to see you over here. :)

Comment: @PacMan-- - nice to meet you too (;

Comment: I'll listen balade in g minor in your honor ;)

Answer (score 5):

First of all, I want to make sure you know [this site](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/mmc/SC1169/SS1577/LN1806).
Get the "[Programming Manual](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/programming_manual/DM00046982.pdf)" from the left column, if you don't have it already.
But what's more important is that you get the "[User's Manual](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/DM00031020.pdf)".

Now, in order to get good documentation on the ARM Cortex-M instruction set (which is provided by ARM), go to the ARM Information Center and look in the [Cortex-M4 Generic User Guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/BABIHJGA.html). There's also timing information in the [Cortex-M4 Technical Reference Manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0439d/CHDDIGAC.html)

Unfortunately I cannot provide you with a direct answer to the problem, as I do not have experience with STM microcontrollers, but I can help you a little anyway.

For information on the GPIO pins, open the User's Manual (DM00031020.pdf) also called RM0090 and read Chapter 8.

I also found a [GPIO tutorial](http://stm32f4-discovery.com/2014/04/stm32f429-discovery-gpio-tutorial-with-onboard-leds-and-button/), which may be helpful.

Though I have not yet used STM, I think they make fine microcontrollers; and it's not the worst documentation I've seen (so you're quite lucky).

From what I can tell by reading the resources I've provided, you need to...

1. Very important: **Turn on clock power for the GPIO. If you don't, you can't access any registers**; this could be what's wrong.
2. Set the speed of the GPIO pins you're about to use (see the reference manual)
3. Configure the pins (it seems you've got that under control)
4. Write the pin values to change them or read the state of the pins.

As my knowledge aren't specific on this product, I can't really go much further.
-But you may also find help at [my.st.com](http://my.st.com/) and the [ARM Connected Community](http://community.arm.com)

Comment: Thank you for the time to write this answer. Although, the "Maestro" Chopin was a bit more precise, I think your answer will give hint to people with similar problems.

Comment: What's important is that you've got it working; besides, Freddie deserves some credit for all the [hard work](http://www.freddiechopin.info/) he's doing. :)

Comment: Note: For the record, I now have good experience with STM; they indeed are better than any other microcontrollers I've been using.

Comment: I have experience only with AVR and STM, and I think STM are not better than AVR, neither worse.

Comment: Well, you can't really compare a porche to roller skates. AVR runs at maximum 20MHz, it does not allow for adding a high speed interface such as a TFT RGB screen, it does not have I2S, it does not have DMA, it uses plenty of power, and a zillion other things. STM32F4 runs at 168 MHz or higher, it has SD card interface (high speed; not boring the SPI stuff), its power consumption is very low. -So in my opinion, an 8-bit AVR is like an 8-bit computer from the early 80's trying to compare with a 32-bit computer from the late 90's.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. But still the larger code database of AVR, the Arduino, the price, and etc. All that shouldn't be neglected. I haven't done any research on power performance if you share some data comparing latest models will be very nice. ;)

Comment: And the STM can emulate the AVR instruction set in real-time, but the AVR cannot do the same the other way.

Comment: Which is not a huge plus, considering the number of cases running AVR assembly on STM. I would prefer as a plus the AVR studio, which is open source and free of charge compare to the other IDE supporting STM I'm aware of like the uVision which costs 5K euros for example, though it's indeed a super IDE. Whether it's superiority costs really 5K is another question...

Comment: So it's like the Greek philosopher that said it's not important to can many things, but to can useful things.